# Is there a real-life java example defining when it is better to use a one-dimensional array instead of an arraylist?

Tags: java, arrays, performance, arraylist

I am aware that:

In the case of choosing between a one-dimensional array and an arraylist, arraylists should always be the preferable choice with one main exception; when collecting primitive values AND efficiency is an issue. 
Since the ArrayList uses arrays internally, high performance (in terms of processing time and memory footprint) is similar to arrays when performing operations on Object types. However, ArrayList performance suffers when operating on primitive types, such as int or long, since ArrayList requires all elements to be wrapped in an Object (such as Integer or Long). While autoboxing reduces the amount of code required for wrapping and unwrapping, it does not remove the performance issues, as wrapper objects are still being created.

But I am searching for a real-life example where i would be collecting primitive values AND efficiency is an issue. Can you think of one?

Comment: I used to work for a bioinformatics company, we used double[] for buffering data that we wanted to plot in real-time. I expect a lot of graphical stuff would use primitive arrays.

Comment: A lot of graphics work uses arrays as you are dealing primitive doubles.  I worked on a physics engine(similar to Autocad w/ simulation) and I used double[] for all of the iterative loop closure algorithms because of the speed.  The algorithms needed to run thousands of times per second, so every little improvement in performance helped.

Comment: You can access any index of an array right after its created. Setting/getting elements at an index in an array list require preloading it with elements, up to that index.

Comment: Inside `ArrayList` itself. ;) Whenever you want to read/write data as a `byte[]`

Answer (score 1):

[SCIENCE](http://xkcd.com/54/).  It's very common to have one or more sensors collecting a fixed number of data values per time interval.  E.g. think of hundreds of thermometers collecting the temperature every millisecond.

Answer (score 1):

Or maths, where you have a matrix or vector of doubles and wish to sum / aggregate them in some way.  Here the unboxing overhead would be large with many values.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the only reason for using an array though.

Whenever you need a fixed size, indexable collection, arrays are a more natural choice. If you want to store an IPv4 address for example, it would be awkward to store the bytes in a list instead of a byte array. Even though in terms of performance it probably doesn't matter.

And before generics were introduced, arrays were the only way to guarantee type safety.

If you're looking for examples of where efficiency is key, look no further than socket/file I/O. Using lists as buffers instead of arrays would be quite ineffective.

Answer (score 0):

Typically while implementing algorithms people work on int/float instead of Integer etc. So there, arrays are best choice. Even efficiency increases.

More non-technical observation:

People start programming by learning C in initial days at school / university.(general observation...not valid in 100% cases). Mentality to use array to solve problems is drilled in our brains and we tend to try out with arrays..atleast while giving initial thoughts to problems, people think in terms of arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I've used arrays anytime I've created a byte buffer.  If you know the exact size of the structure (as you probably should for a buffer), it's much easier and faster to use an array rather than a Collection.